# Paging 3 call api continuously in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, android-paging-3

I'm using the Paging 3 library with recyclerView in NestedScrollView, but it calls load() function continuously even when not scrolling or touching. I don't know what should i do to fix this issue. I have researched and found that recyclerView inside nestedScrollView is the main reason for this issue

Is there any way such as change the XML layout or use another adapter? Thank you everyone!